# Handle mouseclick/doubleclick/mousedown and raise to child

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I'm using a Thumb inside a ListBoxItem to move the item around a Canvas.
The thumb cover the entire surface of the ListBoxItem. 
Since the ListBoxItem can contain for example a TextBox, i'd like to intercept double clicks (at the moment swallowed by the Thumb) and relay them directly to the Texbox.

I tried with a behavior with no luck (the event is not received by the targetElement)... here's the code, any help?

```
public sealed class BubbleDoubleClickEvent : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    #region TargetElement
    public UIElement TargetElement
    {
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue( TargetElementProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( TargetElementProperty, value ); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TargetElement.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetElementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "TargetElement", typeof( UIElement ), typeof( BubbleDoubleClickEvent ) );
    #endregion

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseDown;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        if( e.ClickCount == 2 )
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            var e2 = new MouseButtonEventArgs( e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.ChangedButton );
            e2.RoutedEvent = Control.PreviewMouseDoubleClickEvent;

            var target = TargetElement ?? AssociatedObject;
            target.RaiseEvent( e2 );
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown -= AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseDown;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

The Listbox defines the ItemContainerStyle template similar to this:

```
<Grid>
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{Binding}"    ContentTemplate="{Binding ..., Path=ItemTemplate }" />

   <Thumb x:Name="moveThumb" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:BubbleDoubleClickEvent TargetElement="{Binding   ElementName=contentPresenter}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   </Thumb>
</Grid>
```

Comment: <Thumb  IsHitTestVisible="False">

Comment: @cdmnk ...this would not work and would still need to relay the event to inner content. I'd have to do 1 double click to turn of hittest and 1 click to select the textbox